# Flutter : Stop or Cancel or Abort a page loading in webview

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, dart-webui

I would like to know to stop or cancel or abort a page loading in the webview of Flutter.
The controller does not seem to have stop() or abort() method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try load blank page from controller for cancel or stop previous load:

```
_webViewController.loadUrl("about:blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript:

```
webViewController.runJavaScript('window.stop();')
```

package: webview_flutter: ^4.0.1